# Cannot declare properties with different property type

Tags: c#

[image: http://imageshack.us/f/403/kasta6.png/]

On the link I show you all my classes in my program

I have properties in my `customerframe` class like this:

```
 public string firstName { get; set; }
 public string lastName { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Phone phone { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Email email { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Address addressinfo { get; set; }
 public string city { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Countries countryinfo { get; set; }
 public string street { get; set; }
 public string zipcode { get; set; }
```

but my problem is that when doing this I get error pointing to these 4 properties

```
public CustomerFiles.Phone phone { get; set; }
public CustomerFiles.Email email { get; set; }
public CustomerFiles.Address addressinfo { get; set; }
public CustomerFiles.Countries countryinfo { get; set; }
```

The error is this

> inconsistent accessibility property type is less accessible than
>   property

Further down in class and I'll do the following:

```
        contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
        firstName = contact.FirstName;

        contact.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
        lastName = contact.LastName;

        contact.PhoneData = tbCellPhone.Text;
        phone = contact.PhoneData;

        contact.EmailData = tbHomePhone.Text;
        email = contact.EmailData;

        //inside address class
        address.City = tbCity.Text;
        city = address.City;

        address.Country = cbCountry.Text;
       countryinfo = address.Country;

        address.Street = tbStreet.Text;
        street = address.Street;

        address.ZipCode = tbZipCode.Text;
        zipcode = address.ZipCode;
```

But why do I get problem with my properties? How can I solve this to make it work? thanks in advance

Comment: Have in mind that the correct way of naming properties is to start Capital.

Comment: That image is not a class diagram :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you created the CustomerFiles.Phone class it would look something like:

```
class Phone { }
```

This means that the class is internal.  You can't expose an internal class via a public property.  That is crazy talk.

To fix, you should either change the class to be public:

```
public class Phone { }
```

Or the property to be internal:

```
 internal CustomerFiles.Phone phone { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks alot that solved it. Next problem i have is this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'CustomerRegister1.CustomerFiles.Phone' pointing to contact.PhoneData = tbCellPhone.Text;

Comment: I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark and guess that 1, Text is a string, 2, PhoneData is a Phone, 3, strings and Phones are not the same thing.  It wants you to write a little code to convert the text into a phone.

Comment: Also, now that your origional question has been answered it is polite to upvote all the answers which helped you.  It makes everyone happy.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, the type `CustomerFiles.Phone` (or its containing type `CustomerFiles`, if it's a type rather than a namespace) does not have a visibility of `public`. Since the property you created that returns the type is public, the type itself needs to be `public` as well.

Comment: Otherwise the one that calls the phone property could not know what CustomerFiles.Phone is because it is not public.

Answer (score 2):

First change all types to Public to avoid the accessibility problem.
Secondly can't you just change

```
 public CustomerFiles.Phone phone { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Email email { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Address addressinfo { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles.Countries countryinfo { get; set; }
```

to

```
public CustomerFiles customer {get; set;}
```

Or do you have to access them individually?

/J

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that those types are private or protected but you are trying to surface them with public getters and setters. Make the classes public

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

> CustomerFiles.Phone
>   CustomerFiles.Email 
>   CustomerFiles.Address
>   CustomerFiles.Countries

are public.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class customerframe
{
public string firstName { get; set; }
 public string lastName { get; set; }
 public string city { get; set; }
 public string street { get; set; }
 public string zipcode { get; set; }
 public CustomerFiles CustomerFiles { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerFiles 
{
public Phone phone { get; set; }
public Email email { get; set; }
public Address addressinfo { get; set; }
public Countries countryinfo { get; set; }

}
```